# Why does the "yes | sleep 10" pipe not fail

Tags: bash, pipe

In thinking about how to implement a certain feature in one of my own programs I've been wondering how bash handles pipes of the following nature internally:

```
yes | sleep 10
```

This obviously does nothing but I don't understand how this does not result in an error. I would have thought that either:

- because `sleep` does not read from stdin, the pipe connecting both processes would fill up and cause `yes` to block indefinitely when it attempts to write to the now full pipe
- if non-blocking IO is used, errors should occur if `yes` is executed first and writes to the pipe before the `sleep` process is even run and thus no process is connected to the read end of the pipe

I guess this is some major misunderstanding on my part. I've tried looking at the bash source code but that's gone over my head.

Comment: On my system i get `yes: standard output: Broken pipe`, don't you get that? If you mean why `$?` is equal to 0, it's because you didn't set `-o pipefail`, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html). The exit status of the pipeline is the status of the rightmost command, `sleep 10` returns success. And the right process on the pipeline is runned first (in time) because first a process needs to be listening on stdin for the other to start sending.

Comment: Even if `yes` is blocked writing to a full pipe, why would that cause an error? It will continue trying until the pipe goes away, at which point you'll get the error that Kamil Cuk reports seeing.  What error are you expecting to see?

Comment: I don't get that error (I'm using bash 4.4.23 on Arch). I would have thought that a write to a full pipe would block even after the reading file descriptor was close but I suppose that might not be the case, I think I might just try that out. Also I'm not too sure about the right process having to run first, on my system the commands that make up a pipe are not always started right to left.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what actually happens when you run the shell command `yes | sleep 10`.

First the shell creates an [anonymous pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe) using the [`pipe` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html). The `pipe` system call opens two file descriptors which are the read end and the write end of the pipe. Whatever gets written to the write end becomes available for reading from the read end.

After this, the shell creates two child processes using the [`fork` system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)). The two children run in parallel.

- In one child, the shell connects the write end of the pipe to standard output and closes the read end. Then the shell calls the [`execve` system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)) to replace the code image in this process by the code image of `yes`.
  The program `yes` writes to the pipe as long as it can. If there isn't an active `read` call on the read end of the pipe, the `write` call just blocks. (There's actually a small buffer which `write` will fill up before blocking, but this doesn't matter here.)
- In the other child, the shell connects the read end of the pipe to standard input and closes the write end. Then the shell calls the `execve` system call to replace the code image in this process by the code image of `sleep`.
  The program `sleep` does nothing for 10 seconds.
- The original shell process closes both ends of the pipe and waits for both of its children to exit (using the [`wait` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html)).

Once the 10 seconds are up, the process running `sleep` exits. At this point, the read end of the pipe is no longer open in any process. When a process tries to write to a pipe whose read end is not open in any process, the kernel sends a [`SIGPIPE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGPIPE) signal to the writing process. Thus the process running `yes` is killed by the SIGPIPE signal.

At this point, the shell detects that its child processes on both sides of the pipeline have exited. The pipeline command returns the status of the right-hand side, which is 0 (`sleep` exits successfully).

> because sleep does not read from stdin, the pipe connecting both processes would fill up and cause yes to block indefinitely when it attempts to write to the now full pipe

This is correct.

> if non-blocking IO is used, errors should occur if yes is executed first and writes to the pipe before the sleep process is even run and thus no process is connected to the read end of the pipe

This is not correct in several places. `yes` does not use non-blocking IO. It's executed in parallel with `sleep`, not first. There is never any point in time when no process is connected to the read end of the pipe, not until `sleep` exits. Depending on the timing, it's possible that `yes` will start writing before `sleep` starts executing, maybe even before the child process for the `sleep` program is forked, but the read end became open when the `pipe` call returned, at the same time as the write end became open.

Comment: So does `yes` eventually receive `EPIPE` when `sleep` exits while yes is in the middle of a blocking write to the full pipe? Because `yes` does terminate eventually.

Comment: No. `yes` receives a SIGPIPE signal while it's executing a `write` system call. This system call does not return because the process dies due to the signal.

Comment: @Peter You only see `EPIPE` if you've ignored `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: Ah yes, `SIGPIPE` is what I meant. I think I've got it now.